How to cleanup the registry entries created while adding a dynamic device after removal in windows?
I am developing an audio driver using WDF and ACX framework where I use WDF Childlists to enumerate multiple devices dynamically. When I add a device, There will be some registry entries will be created at HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum But when I remove the device, There entries will not be deleted. But if I uninstalled the driver, these will be removed.
Above behavior is causing the name duplication in the endpoint (2 - Endpoint Name) in below scenario.
Working Scenario:

Add a device with Device Description: Test Audio , Hardware ID: IPAUD\dev1

Add another device with Device Description: Test Audio , Hardware ID: IPAUD\dev2

This will create 2 endpoints. Speaker(Test Audio) and Speaker(2 - Test Audio) And this is expected.


Error Scenario:

Add a device with Device Description: Test Audio , Hardware ID: IPAUD\dev1

This will create an endpoint. Speaker(Test Audio).

Remove the above added device.

Add a device with Device Description: Test Audio , Hardware ID: IPAUD\dev2

This will create and endpoint. Speaker(2 - Test Audio) But expected behavior is to create endpoint with name Speaker(Test Audio)


As mentioned above, Windows is keeping the registry entries for each created devices. and the duplication in the name in the entries is causing the issue.
Searched for ways to edit/delete registry entries. Found out that HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum should not be modified.
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum
